# derivative function at certain point

Tags: limits, derivatives

I encountered this proof durring my self studing and it really makes my life harder.
This is function $f$ $\colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ which derivative at point $a$, such that $f(a) > 0$.

I need to prove that :
$\lim_{x\to 0}( \frac{f(x)}{f(a)})^\frac{1}{ lnx - lna} = \frac{f'(a)}{f(a)}\cdot a$

So far I found that the left side equal to $1$ (only if $\ln a$ is defined which means $a>0$).
for the other side I tried to break it into the definition of derivation by $\lim$ but no success so far.

I would like to hear some good idea how to continue from here.

Comment: No, the left side is not equal to $1,$ and on the right side you need to exponentiate. Pay good attention to the hint from Atmos.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**
$$
\left(\frac{f\left(x\right)}{f\left(a\right)}\right)^{1/(\ln(x)-\ln(a))}=\text{exp}\left(\frac{\ln\left(f\left(x\right)\right)-\ln\left(f\left(a\right)\right)}{\ln(x)-\ln(a)}\right)
$$

Comment: I tried to do so already but can't see how it solve.

Comment: Maybe the $X$ should go to $a$ and not to 0 ?